# How to set conditions in a data frame and then average the values and replace them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame.

```
   a    b 
0  0.5  1
1  2@3  4 
2  1   4@4
```

I want to set a condition for each column to check if "@" is present for each row values. And if it is, then I need to split the values and average them and replace them as new values. The values that do not have "@" do not have to go through any of the operations. My result should be:

```
   a    b 
0  0.5  1
1  2.5  4 
2  1   4
```

2@3---need to be split as 2 and 3 and the average of these values need to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

You could `stack` + `str.split` + `explode` + `astype(float)` to create a MultiIndex Series of dtype float out of `df`. Then `groupby` the index, find `mean` and `unstack` to build back the DataFrame:

```
out = (df.stack().str.split('@').explode().astype(float)
       .groupby(level=[0,1]).mean().unstack())
```

Output:

```
     a    b
0  0.5  1.0
1  2.5  4.0
2  1.0  4.0
```

Comment: Okay, I had done a minor mistake. but I got a different error now: could not convert string to float: '…'

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not an optimal solution, one way could be as following

```
import pandas as pd

for col in df.columns:
    for idx, i in enumerate(df[col]):
        if '@' in str(i):
            temp = [int(j) for j in str(i).split('@')]
            avg = sum(temp) / len(temp)
            df.loc[idx, col] = avg
print(df)
```

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '15.75

Comment: ame 'num' is not defined

Comment: Fixed: 'num' is not defined